# Can't find a way to place an app in Launchpad

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, launchpad

I've dragged the app into both Applications folders. I've tried to drag it onto the Launchpad icon in the Dock. But that didn't do anything. The only thing that worked was making an alias and then putting that into the Applications folder.

Note that the app is torrented. Does that make a difference?

Comment: An application in the top level Application folder will appear in the Launchpad. Usually as the last item.

Comment: Otherwise try CMD-dragging it onto the Launchpad icon